# Excel VBA Concatenate only visible cells of filtered column. Test code included

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

Good day all,

I'm trying to concatenate a filtered column into a single cell separated with commas. I know little about coding, the code provided are by others after hours of searching.

So far, this function works but also concatenates invisible, filtered out cells:

```
Function test1(myRange As Range)
Dim aOutput
For Each entry In myRange
    If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
        aOutput = aOutput & entry.Value & ", "
    End If
Next
test1 = Left(aOutput, Len(aOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

And this one works well where it will also remove duplicates from the range, but has the same problem:

```
Function test2(ByRef rRng As Range, Optional ByVal sDelim As String = ", ") As String
Dim oDict As Object
Dim rCell As Range
Dim sTxt As String
Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With oDict
    For Each rCell In rRng
        If .Exists(rCell.Text) Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            .Add rCell.Text, rCell.Text
            sTxt = sTxt & sDelim & rCell.Text
        End If
    Next rCell
End With
    test2 = Mid(sTxt, Len(sDelim) + 1)
End Function
```

Is it possible to alter the two functions to ignore invisible, filtered out cells in a column?

Thanks for reading,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function test1(myRange As Range)
    Dim aOutput As String, entry As Range
    For Each entry In myRange
        If entry.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            aOutput = aOutput & entry.Value & ", "
        End If
    Next
    test1 = Left(aOutput, Len(aOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: @user2284877 You would use a `Collection` to remove duplicateds

Answer (score 1):

Sure - inside your functions and before any executable instruction, declare a new variable myRangeVisible like this:

```
Dim myRangeVisible as Range
```

and set it up to include only visible cells from inside myRange

```
Set myRangeVisible = myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

And use this range as your source range for all operations in your functions code

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to alter the function with this help!