# Concatenate Only the Visible Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following VBA to concatenate rows with a common ID

```
Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
Dim a, i As Long
a = rng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
If a(i, 1) = BaseValue Then JoinAll = JoinAll & _
    IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a(i, 3)
Next
End Function
```

As an example:

```
ID | Date   | Purchase | Concat Value
1  | 3/4/16 | Car      | Car, Cap
2  | 5/2/12 | Cat      | Cat
1  | 6/2/13 | Cap      | Cap
```

When run, this creates Car, Cap.

However, this is a table with a filter, and once it is filtered to this:

```
ID | Date   | Purchase | Concat Value
1  | 3/4/16 | Car      | Car, Cap 
2  | 5/2/12 | Cat      | Cat
```

It still shows Car, Cap instead of ignoring that Cap is not visible.

I have seen this answer, but don't see how to make it work with my current VBA:

[Excel VBA Concatenate only visible cells of filtered column. Test code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367313/excel-vba-concatenate-only-visible-cells-of-filtered-column-test-code-included)

UPDATE: 
Using this I am getting only the visible items joined, but I need it to return the values in column 3. This only returns the values in column 1:

```
Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)

For Each a In rng
If a = BaseValue And a.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a
End If
Next a
End Function
```

Comment: Its not clear exactly what you are trying to concatenate. This would help: a dump of the structure of your data with a couple of rows of dummy data (minimal example). Identifying exactly what you are trying to concatenate - i.e. what cells in the row you are cat'ting and what sort of results are you expecting...etc etc. Seeing that a question has had some time/effort put in to it encourages answers, and more of them.

Comment: I have revised my question to have more detail around structure

Comment: OK. Format still smelly, but I can work with that :-)

Comment: What about if I added another row with ID=1, DATE=blah, Purchase=Car, which is exactly the same purchase as row 1. What are you expecting cat'ting to show? Two cars (i.e. Car, Cap, Car) or (Car(2), Cap) or (Car, Cap) i.e. it does not count/care about repeat values.

Comment: Answer below. Checked as working. You had `a.EntireRow.Hidden=False`, I think it should be `rng.EntireRow.Hidden=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. There is a typo/bug in your original code as `a=rng.value`, so `a` should be `rng` when considering the hidden rows.

```
 Function JoinAll3(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
    Dim a, i As Long
    a = rng.Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            If a(i, 1) = BaseValue And rng(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                JoinAll3 = JoinAll3 & IIf(JoinAll3 = "", "", delim) & a(i, 3)
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
For each val in rng.Columns(3).Cells
    If val = BaseValue And val.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & val
    End If
Next val
```

Comment: It states "Compile error Argument not optional". Here is my current code:    Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
Dim a, i As Long
a = rng.Value
For Each Val In rng
    If Val = BaseValue And Val.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & Val
    End If
Next Val
End Function

Comment: You can remove `Dim a, i as Long a=rng.Value`

Comment: That works, almost, but I need it to return the value in column 3. That is where a(i, 3) came in.

Comment: Looking closer, it is returning the values from the group ahead of it in order. Example, returning purchases for client id of 232 instead of 233, 234 where it should be 235. Here is my current VBA   Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)

For Each a In rng
    If a = BaseValue And a.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a(i, 3)
    End If
Next a
End Function

Comment: Why are using `a(i,3)` by the looks of your function you aren't incrementing your i value. To get just the third Column use `For each val in rng.Columns(3).Cells` I've updated my original code - Try using that

Comment: @Kode  Your code would work as you wish if you change a(i,3) to a(1,3).  Not the most efficient code, but workable.  And I suspect the **i** was just a typo.

Comment: works when `a.EntireRow` is replaced with `rng.EntireRow` as `a=rng.value` with `rng` being the range object.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried rng.Columns(3).Cells but it was returning 0. Changing to either Rusan's or Ron's adaption to Tom's worked. Wish I could offer equal points to all.